# performing calculations on a column for every 2 rows and displaying the result for the group

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table (CURRENT) which is extracted from a SQL query. Each benchmark has two data points.
i need to calculate the difference of the two data points (i.e. more recent data point - less recent data point) and have the result displayed alongside the rows.

i guess it has to do with group by, but this is my weakest area in sql and i am not sure how to return the result to display alongside the grouped rows. i've maanged to calculate the difference by doing a "group by BENCHMARK" and then have the MAX(VALUE) - Min(VALUE),  but realised this is dumb as i have no way of knowing the signage. even if i can do so, i do not know how to display the calculated value. any assitance pls?

thanks. (oracle pls)

```html
CURRENT    
 DATEF     BENCHMARK VALUE 
 31-Jul-14 A       100 
 31-Aug-14 A       101 
 31-Jul-14 B       101 
 31-Aug-14 B       99 
 31-Jul-14 C       100 
 31-Aug-14 C       101 
 31-Jul-14 D       100 
 31-Aug-14 D       100 
 31-Jul-14 E       101 
 31-Aug-14 E       102 
    

EITHER THIS:    
    
 DATEF     BENCHMARK   VALUE DIFFERENCE
 31-Jul-14 A         100     1
 31-Aug-14 A         101     1
 31-Jul-14 B         101     -2
 31-Aug-14 B           99     -2
 31-Jul-14 C         100     1
 31-Aug-14 C           101     1  
 31-Jul-14 D         100     0
 31-Aug-14 D         100     0
 31-Jul-14 E         101     1
 31-Aug-14 E         102     1



OR THIS:    
    
 DATEF     BENCHMARK   VALUE DIFFERENCE
 31-Jul-14 A         100     
 31-Aug-14 A         101     1
 31-Jul-14 B         101     
 31-Aug-14 B           99     -2
 31-Jul-14 C         100     
 31-Aug-14 C           101     1  
 31-Jul-14 D         100     
 31-Aug-14 D         100     0
 31-Jul-14 E         101     
 31-Aug-14 E         102     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle offers the `FIRST_VALUE()` and `LAST_VALUE()` functions which seem to be exactly what you need.  Your problem is one of analytic/window functions, not aggregation.

```
select c.*,
       (last_value(value) over (partition by benchmark order by datef range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) -
        first_value(value) over (partition by benchmark order by datef range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
       ) as difference
from current c;
```

EDIT:

Or, I think you can simplify the above to:

```
select c.*,
       (first_value(value) over (partition by benchmark order by datef desc) -
        first_value(value) over (partition by benchmark order by datef)
       ) as difference
from current c;
```

Comment: thnanks.  its works to what i want ... however i do need to add in "RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING" in order to return LAST_VALUE correctly. this clause is kinda hard to explain to end-users.

Comment: @theluncheonmeat . . . That is a subtle issue.  I don't think you need the `range` clause if you use `first_value()` and change the order of the sort.  The `order by` makes the analytic function cumulative, which implicitly adds a `range between unbounded preceding and current row`.  You need the `range` to override this, or to use `first_value` so the cumulative version returns what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this?

```
select benchmark, max(value) keep (dense_rank first order by datef) - 
                  max(value) keep (dense_rank last  order by datef) difference
  from current
 group by benchmark
```

This query take `value` for minimal `datef` and subtracts from it `value` for maximal `datef`. Is it what you want?

Or you can also use `lag`/`lead` analytical functions.

Comment: i think this works too, however i do not understand what does max(Value) do. why is there a need to put max(value) and not simply value, since "dense_rank first order by datef" already indicate i want the first ordered result...

Comment: @theluncheonmeat Expression `max(value) keep (dense_rank first order by datef)` means: "sort table by `datef` and take maximal `value` from a row with maximal `datef`"